# Excel VLOOKUP return blank instead of 0 or #na

Tags: excel

So I have a UserForm where the user enters the data and it is saved in a single sheet. The text boxes in the UserForm can be filled in or left blank. I was wondering why, when I use the VLOOKUP formula, the return value of the blank data is equal to 0?

`=IF(LEN(VLOOKUP($F$18,G1_Q1,15,0))=0,"",VLOOKUP($F$18,G1_Q1,15,0))`

This formula works in terms of the 0, but when I use it on other columns and change the `G1_Q1` to `G1_Q2`, it returns the **#N/A** error. Note that, there is no data of the  `value` in the `G1_Q2`.

Is there a formula that will not return 0 or N/A and will instead leave the cell value blank?

Comment: Use `IFERROR(your formula, "")`.

Comment: @Harun24HR it worked! Thanks!

Comment: `XLOOKUP` if you have 365 has an option for nothing found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning 0 from an empty cell is standard behaviour in Excel - try entering =B1 in A1 of a blank sheet.

If you don't want to see the 0 then you could adjust the formula.

### Excel 365

```
=LET(res, VLOOKUP($F$18,G1_Q1,15,0), IF(OR(ISERROR(res), res=0), "", res))
```

### Previous versions

```
=IF(OR(ISERROR(VLOOKUP($F$18,G1_Q1,15,0)), VLOOKUP($F$18,G1_Q1,15,0)=0), "", VLOOKUP($F$18,G1_Q1,15,0))
```

Note, you could also hide 0 using formatting.